# How to know which button user clicked and its text and id in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application, buttonclick

Through out the whole android application I want to capture button click, radio button clicks, link click etc... basically a user interaction in whole android application. Is there any common method to detect which element user click and its values.?

Comment: Try with fragment inside activity here you can get the value of button or which you want from multiple fragment to aone place in main activity.... another way you can get inside Application class which you can access anywhere inside app using application instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using onCickListener() on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin:

1. Add id to button in .xml files with `android:id="@+id/nameOfButton"`. Every button needs an unique name.
2. In .kt file, use `setOnClickListener` with the id to set up the action when user click the button.
3. If there are several buttons, just follow step 1 and 2.

Example: 
step 1

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save" />
```

step 2

```
buttonSave.setOnclickListenter {
    //TODO: your code goes here
}
```

Comment: thanks justin for your help. but i need it generic way. i need to track all the button or clicked element in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple you just need to get the text and id of button from the onclick method. Here is java and xml code for it:
***XML***:

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/button"
  android:onclick="getid"
  android:text="Save" />
```

***JAVA***:

```
public void getid(View v){
  int id = v.getId();
  String text = v.getText();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, above code will works only for "getid", but i need it in dynamic way. but need in way ,in application whatever the button user click i need the details. it should be common for all the button in application.

Comment: Then you could set `button.setOnClickListener(getid());` to all required button

Comment: so it will capture all the button in application right?

Comment: You need to implement them in each one of them individually. As far as I am concerned there is no way to do that to all button at once.

Comment: or else is there any way to capture what element i clicked, like button or icon or dropdown or checkbox like that?

Comment: In general until and unless you have `clickListener` there is no way to do so but you might want to use `Listview` to display alot of button at once and capture them with only single `onItemClickListener` if you are interested then I will provide an answer for that

Comment: thanks it worked out for me

Answer (score 0):

As @Muthukumar Lenin asked here is listview in xml and java

***XML***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/rl"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:padding="10dp"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textStyle="italic"
      android:textColor="#5f65ff"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:text="Choose is the best football player?"/>
   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/listview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@id/textview" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

***JAVA***:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
      final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
      String[] players = new String[] {"CR7", "Messi", "Hazard", "Neymar"};
      List<String> Players_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(players));
      ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Players_list);
      listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            textView.setText("The best football player is : " + selectedItem);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Some of these code are from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-handle-the-click-event-in-listview-in-android) and some are edited by me.